# Copy from a dynamic range in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks, on being a template of the analyses, the other being the source of our database with no formatting at all.

I have a button that I click, select the file and it imports every row until there is a blank on the first column of the range (Column A in my case) this is a good thing. But I have cases where the first column is filled with blanks, and the second column doesn't have a single blank.

So I want to copy until Column B hits a blank, but still have column A copied.

Bellow is my code at the moment

```
Sub test()
    Dim fileName As Variant
        
    fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    
    If fileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open fileName:=fileName
        MsgBox "Success!", copy()
    End If
End Function


Function copy()
    Dim myrange

    Set myrange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:L3")
    myrange.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10")
End Function
```

Comment: Try to `Set myrange = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns(1)` then `myrange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10")` and get rid of all the other lines in `copy()`

Comment: there is never a reason to use `Select`. Use direct assignment of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below finds the # rows under "A3:L3" and copies the contents (as values) under "A10". It find the first blank in column A, and column B, and uses the largest of the two.

```
Public Sub CopyInSheet1()

    Dim myrange As Range
    Set myrange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
    
    ' Find non-empty rows (check two columns)
    Dim n_rows_A As Long, n_rows_B As Long, n_rows As Long
    n_rows_A = CountRows(myrange)
    n_rows_B = CountRows(myrange.Offset(0, 1))
    n_rows = WorksheetFunction.Max(n_rows_A, n_rows_B)
    
    ' Do the copy here
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10").Resize(n_rows, 12).Value = _
        myrange.Resize(n_rows, 12).Value

End Sub

Function CountRows(ByRef r As Range) As Long
    If IsEmpty(r) Then
        CountRows = 0
    ElseIf IsEmpty(r.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        CountRows = 1
    Else
        CountRows = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    End If
End Function
```